# Child div defining Parent height

Tags: css, html

```
<body>
<div id="parent">
    <div id="childRightCol"></div>
    <div id="childLeftCol"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Parent's height is suppose to be dynamic and stretches to the max height defined by the child. ChildRight dynamically changes height but I want it to be 100% height of parent. ChildLeft some times defines the height of parent.

The problem is that because ChildLeft defines the height of the parent. Height:100% on childright doesn't work because parent's height isn't defined. Please help.

```
id="news-flicker-container"
id="news-flicker-userbars"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `display: none` and `display: block` to toggle visibility, use `visibility: hidden` and `visibility: visible` which keeps the size of the elements.

To prevent the articles form stacking on top of each other, you have to compensate. This can be achieved by floating all the articles to the left of each other, and give them all but the first a negative margin so they all remain at the same location.

See **[this demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/8aGr9/1/)** which demonstrates two situations, i.e. an article with less height then the right column and one with larger height then the right column. In both cases the height of the left column (the height of the largest article) decides the height of the parent div.

The basic requirements for the CSS:

```
#news-flicker-container {
    float: left;
}
#news-flicker-userbars {
    float: left;
}
#news-flicker-container article {
    width: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -100%;
}
#news-flicker-container article:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this work if the largest element is not the first article?

Comment: It works for every article being the largest, see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8aGr9/2/) where first article is largest. The special style for the first article is just because the first article is already in place/at the right location. Giving it also a negative margin would render it out of the column.

Comment: @Harrison In case this doesn't work: simply copying this CSS into your own doesn't do the whole trick yet: it's just a sample of how it works. E.g. I just saw that your article is a child of another div in the left column, so you have to rewrite my example for your specific situation. For me/us it is somewhat difficult because you haven't provided the css nor actual structure yourself. If you want a complete answer, please provide the css and actual markup.

Comment: You solution solves instances where the Left Coumn defines the parent height. Is there any way to configure it so it will work if the right column defines the parent's height?

Comment: @Harrison My solution already solves both columns being the largest. See this altered [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/8aGr9/3/).

Comment: I'm looking at your fiddle and in the second solution the left column's background color doesn't equal the right columns. So I want equal height backgrounds for the columns not articles. Please check out http://nofaceproductions.org/ you may have to clear your cache to see the problem. In my specific case I want specifically so that when the right column extends beyond the left column, the left column will equal the right.

Comment: @Harrison Ah, I understand you now. Then you have to combine the solution of David Oliver like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/8aGr9/4/).

Answer (score 1):

[Equal Height Columns with Cross-Browser CSS](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks)

If you don't need to support IE 6 and 7, this would be a better approach:

[Use CSS display:table for Layout](http://www.onenaught.com/posts/201/use-css-displaytable-for-layout)

Comment: the display table doesn't work for me for some reason I will try the other one later but a simple css solution would be nice.

Comment: This will not work, since OP hides children of the left column with `display: none` and one of those hidden children has to set the height.